# What's the reason a handle for owner window required when creating an common dialog

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, common-dialog

I'm working with common dialog recently and I've found that a `hWndOwner` is required in the structure that passed to functions like `ChooseColor`.

It seems of no difference when I used different `hWndOwner`. What does different `hWndOwner` choosing affects? Are there anything to take care when choosing the owner window?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows

Comment: answer yourself, and gain some points

Comment: See [owned windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows) to learn, why passing an owner is useful.

Comment: [Raymond Chen's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) has a [series of articles on how window modality works](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?s=Modality), particularly in relation to dialog window owners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who commented! Below are the key ideas I've got from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows).

- There are a few things that relates to ownership, as taken from the document:

  > - An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.
  > - The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed.
  > - An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.
- Setting owner to a child window (a window that is not a overlapped window or popup window) is equivalent to setting it to the top-level parent window.
- The ownership could not be transferred after the window is created.

That's what I've learnt by reading the document. It would be much better if someone can give some extra information that is not included in the document.